# Primefaces push in linux

Tags: linux, primefaces, push, atmosphere

I have deployed 2 web applications which have the push (notification) functions.
Firstly, I deploy the first app (PUSH_SERVER) and publish web service. When the web method is called, the notification will be push to the second application.
My configuration for the second app is as below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
    <param-value>myURL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The strange thing is: The push runs really well in Windows. But when I deploy them in Linux, in the same server. The first app is still able to get the notification. However, when I open the second app, I get this error (from FireBug):

```
Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent).
Websocket closed, wasClean: false
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
```

I'm really confusing about this error. Would you give me some suggests?

Comment: Push works fine for me on Linux. Check firewall settings etc

Comment: Well, I strongly highlight "in the same server". When I move 1 app to another server, the push works fine.

Comment: Even in the same server there can be differences like two serlvet containers, bound to different ip adresses different ports and hence different FW rules and even running as different users with different network security rules.